# BluetoothError "Connection reset by peer" when trying to send audio file from Raspberry Pi4 to a smartphone

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi4, bluez

I get the error message:

```
Ausnahme: BluetoothError
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
  File "<string>", line 3, in sendall
_bluetooth.error: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/eggplant/Dokumente/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    sock.sendall(block)
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

when executing the code:

```
from bluetooth import *

server_mac = '34:29:12:5E:09:10'#20:F4:78:56:EF:7D'
port = 3  # Port für OBEX Object Push Profile

sock = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)

try:
    sock.connect((server_mac, port))
    print("Verbunden mit", server_mac)
except BluetoothError as e:
    print("Bluetooth Fehler beim Verbinden:", e)
    sock.close()
    exit(1)

file_path = 'hallo_welt_mp3.wav'
block_size = 1024  # Größe des Datenblocks zum Senden

with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        block = f.read(block_size)
        if not block:
            break  # Ende der Datei erreicht
        try:
            sock.sendall(block)
        except BluetoothError as e:
            print("Bluetooth Fehler beim Senden:", e)
            break

print("Datei erfolgreich gesendet.")
sock.close()
```

What is my mistake and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error `"connection reset by peer"` typically occurs when the remote device (in this case, the smartphone) closes the connection unexpectedly. several reasons for this error, such as a timeout, incompatible Bluetooth profiles, or issues with the Bluetooth connection itself. You can try:

- Verify that the MAC address of the smartphone is correct.
- Check if the smartphone supports the OBEX Object Push Profile (OPP) and if it is enabled. This profile is used for transferring files over Bluetooth.
- Try using a different Bluetooth `library` or `module` on the Raspberry Pi. There are alternative libraries available, such as `PyBluez` or `Bluez`, which might provide better compatibility.